# Problem Aliasing a Command With a Pipeline and an Argument

Tags: email, alias, tcsh

Note: I use tcsh.

I am trying make an alias that will use the mutt command to send an email with a pre-written body and subject line but that will take the alias argument and attach it to the email.  The best I currently have is:

```
alias emailattach 'echo "Message Body" | mutt -a \!:1 -s "Subject" email@somewhere.com'
```

This alias sets just fine, without any whining, but when I try to run it I get the following message:

```
Can't stat email@somewhere.com: No such file or directory
email@somewhere.com: unable to attach file.
```

When I remove `-a \!:1`
I no longer get the error message, so I believe the problem could be focused on this portion of the alias.  The files I've told `emailattach` to attach are real, attachable files (a PDF specifically), so that's not the issue.

I also tried the same alias but without the single quotes and I only got this error:

```
email@somewhere.com: unable to attach file.
```

To see if the pipeline was the crux of the problem I tried the following:

```
alias emailattach mutt -a \!:1 -s "Subject" email@somewhere.com
```

and then tried just running:

```
echo "Message Body" | emailattach /path/to/attachment
```

which gave the same error message as I first listed(`can't stat`...`unable to attach file.`).  However, when I just ran:

```
echo "Message Body" | emailattach
```

I got this error:

```
Bad ! arg selector.
```

Which I assume is just an error saying that I forgot to put in the required argument.

What have I written wrong in my alias that makes it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `alias` around so that the attachment is last in your call to `mutt` like so:

```
$ alias emailattach 'echo "Message Body" | mutt -s "Subject" email@somewhere.com -a \!:1'
```

Doing it this way worked for me.